# N+1 query persists even after using includes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following should load a bunch of associated using JOINS:

```
Event.where(id: @events.map(&:id))
     .includes(
               :user, 
               :event_category, 
               task: [:document_tasks, task_followers: :follower] 
              )
```

Now when I step through each event and use the associations retrieved above, I should not see any N+1 queries:

```
Event.where(id: @events.map(&:id))
     .includes(
                :user,
                :event_category,
                task: [:document_tasks, task_followers: :follower]
      ).each do |event|
        owner = event.task.task_followers.where(owner: true).first.follower
      end
```

But I see a ton of queries like the following:

```
D, [2017-12-06T19:46:17.536892 #26637] DEBUG -- :   TaskFollower Load (2.9ms)  
SELECT  `task_followers`.* FROM `task_followers` 
WHERE `task_followers`.`task_id` = 11635 AND `task_followers`.`owner` = 1  
ORDER BY `task_followers`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
```

Relationships:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :task
    belongs_to :event_category
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :document_tasks, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :task_followers, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :followers, through: :task_followers, dependent: :destroy
    has_one :fullcalendar_engine_event, class_name: 'FullcalendarEngine::Event'
end
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Please post `relationship`s among the classes.

Comment: @HarshGupta I did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is due to your calling `where(owner: true)`. This is causing it to send another query to filter your results. Trying replacing it with `select(&:owner?)` instead.

```
# Change this line
owner = event.task.task_followers.where(owner: true).first.follower
# to this
owner = event.task.task_followers.select(&:owner?).first.follower
```